# How to use direct streaming for SOAP with Spring-WS?

Tags: java, spring, soap, streaming, spring-ws

We want to enable direct streaming of our payload in webservice endpoints. We have to process a large amount of data and want to stream the data while processing.

We use spring-ws-core, in version 2.0.0 and use the `PayloadRootQNameEndpointMapping` as endpoint mapper. As message factory we are using the `AxiomSoapMessageFactory`. We implement the `StreamingPayload` and the corresponding `writeTo(XMLStreamWriter writer)` method, which we use to write our payload (According to the spring-ws JIRA ticket, [SWS-352](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SWS-352)).

This works fine without any errors, but we wanted to stream directly! This is apparently not possible. We made an easy test where we streamed some data to evaluate the behaviour.

```
writer.writeStartElement("exampleResponse")

10000.times
{
    writer.writeStartElement("example")
    writer.writeEndElement()    
}

writer.writeEndElement()
```

We assumed that this will be directly streamed to the consumer/client, so the soap header is already written to our writer and closes after the endpoint is completed. Unfortunately this is not possible, the stream can not be used directly! The stream is wrapped in a `ByteArrayInputStream`, found in the spring-ws source.

The implementation of `StreamingOMDataSource` shows this (can be viewed in [springs FishEye](https://fisheye.springsource.org/browse/~br=trunk/spring-ws/trunk/core/src/main/java/org/springframework/ws/soap/axiom/StreamingOMDataSource.java?r=1689)). The `StreamingOMDataSource` calls your StreamingPayload implementation and gives you a writer for this.

```
public XMLStreamReader getReader() throws XMLStreamException {
   ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
   serialize(bos, null);

   ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(bos.toByteArray());
   return StAXUtils.createXMLStreamReader(bis);
}
```

The method `#serialize()` creates the `XMLStreamWriter` with the `ByteArrayOutputStream` and calls the payload to enable writing, as described above.

```
public void serialize(OutputStream output, OMOutputFormat format) 
       throws XMLStreamException
{
   XMLStreamWriter streamWriter;
   if ([...]) {
      // Create stream writer with defined charset
   }
   else {
       streamWriter = StAXUtils.createXMLStreamWriter(output);
   }
   serialize(streamWriter);
}

public void serialize(XMLStreamWriter xmlWriter) throws XMLStreamException {
   payload.writeTo(xmlWriter);
   xmlWriter.flush();
}
```

So this is not usable for me. Is it possible to achieve direct streaming? Any ideas for this? Thank you in advance!

---

**Update**: I finally created a [JIRA ticket (SWS-704)](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SWS-704) for Spring WS. If you want to see it implemented consider watching/voting it on the JIRA page. Hopefully we get at least an useful reply.

Comment: I dont see that SWS-352 allows for streaming? You know that webservices are over HTTP right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have also to disable the payload caching:

```
<bean id="messageFactory" 
      class="org.springframework.ws.soap.axiom.AxiomSoapMessageFactory">
     <property name="payloadCaching" value="false"/>
</bean>
```

With this setting we are finally able to perform direct streaming for SOAP with Spring WS!

Answer (score 2):

You cannot (should never) stream the data within a web service, as in continously sending XML over the HTTP connection in a single web-service request over time. You will have to make many single web-service calls, or accumulate several calls into one.

If you need high performance, web-services are not great. But you can hand-optimize simple web-services, it is not that hard. But switching to another [transport format](https://github.com/eishay/jvm-serializers/wiki/) would be more 'on the money' if you need higher performance. I'd still keep things over HTTP - especially if you have some authentication requirements.

Comment: If it's that bad to provide streamed webservice, why does JAX-WS RI provides support for sending and receiving large attachments in a streaming fashion? We will think over a chunked data transfer but the Spring-WS implementation is still not useful! Can you explain what's wrong with a streaming implementation based on webservices/HTTP?

Comment: The streaming API is more efficient, the alternative is to build a DOM tree. It is called a streaming API, but this only applies to creating the XML. You have no guarantee, in fact it would be very strange, if the receiver (webservice endpoint) did not read the full request, validate it, and then process its payload as a whole.

Comment: Keep your eyes on the ball; you want to stream your data, you do not need to do webservice streaming to achieve that? What kind of performance do you need, and do you have example of the xml you are sending?

Answer (score 0):

I can only think of a hack for this - stacks(cxf, spring ws etc) would buffer the entire message as they have to validate the response xml, to be able to calculate the cryptographic keys if security is enabled etc.

So the hack would be to write your own custom servlet/spring controller which would handle this specific response and stream out the soap envelope, then your payload, then the end tag of soap envelope. This is assuming you don't have any WSS requirements.