# Can we use multiple message factories in Spring WS?

Tags: java, spring, soap, streaming, spring-ws

I recently solved the [problem of the direct streaming with Spring WS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5165055/how-to-use-direct-streaming-for-soap-with-spring-ws), thanks to Arjen for the fast response. The trick was  to disable payload caching in the Axiom message factory.

I now suffering from that global decision, we have either to enable or disable payload caching for the whole system. We would like to have webservices with streaming and also some which enables validation (which is not possible if payload caching is disabled)

So is it possible to map an specific endpoint to an specific message factory? It's easy to do with webservice clients, but what about endpoints? Any ideas?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right, it's very easy on client side passing the specific `WebServiceMessageFactory` instance to the `WebServiceTemplate` constructor.

Anyway, I guess it's also possible on server side. 
If you can use different url mappings, the simplest way I found out is based on the configuration of two (or more) differents `MessageDispatcherServlet` in your `web.xml`. Then you just have to pass as init parameter the specific bean name of the  `WebServiceMessageFactory` instance you prefer. Something like this:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>ws1</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.ws.transport.http.MessageDispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/conf/ws1-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>messageFactoryBeanName</param-name>
        <param-value>defaultMessageFactory</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>ws2</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.ws.transport.http.MessageDispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/conf/ws2-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>messageFactoryBeanName</param-name>
        <param-value>streamingMessageFactory</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ws1</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/ws1</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ws2</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/ws2</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Then, you just have to add your different message factory beans to your spring-ws context.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much! We also found this solution, we had to enhance this a little bit to make sure not all web services are available for streaming and are blocked out.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to switch messagefactory within a single endpoint, you can achieve that by extending `WebServiceMessageReceiverHandlerAdapter` and overriding `getMessageFactory` method.

```
  public class SwitchableMessageRecieverHandlerAdapter extends WebServiceMessageReceiverHandlerAdapter{

   private WebServiceMessageFactory alternateMessageFactory;

   private String switchOn;

   public void setSwitchOn(String switchOn) {
    this.switchOn = switchOn;
   }

   public String getSwitchOn() {
    return switchOn;
   }

   public WebServiceMessageFactory getAlternateMessageFactory() {
       return alternateMessageFactory;
   }

   public void setAlternateMessageFactory(WebServiceMessageFactory alternateMessageFactory) {
       this.alternateMessageFactory = alternateMessageFactory;
   }

    public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
        Assert.notNull(alternateMessageFactory, "alternateMessageFactory is required");
        Assert.notNull(switchOn, "switchOn parameter is required");
    }

    @Override
    public WebServiceMessageFactory getMessageFactory() {
        TransportContext transport = TransportContextHolder.getTransportContext();

        if(transport!=null && transport.getConnection() instanceof HttpServletConnection){
            HttpServletConnection httpCon = (HttpServletConnection)(transport.getConnection());
            if(getSwitchOn().equals(httpCon.getHttpServletRequest().getHeader("soapAction"))){
                return alternateMessageFactory;
            }
        }

        return super.getMessageFactory();

    }

}
```

Now configure `SwitchableMessageRecieverHandlerAdapter` in your context file by providing `alternateMessageFactory` and soap actions for which you want to use `alternateMessageFactory`

```
<bean id="messageFactory" class="org.springframework.ws.samples.mtom.service.AxiomMtomEnabledSoapMessageFactory">
        <property name="payloadCaching" value="true"/>
        <property name="attachmentCaching" value="true"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="saajMessageFactory" class="org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessageFactory"/>

    <bean id="switchableMessageReciever" class="SwitchableMessageRecieverHandlerAdapter">
        <property name="alternateMessageFactory" ref="saajMessageFactory"/>
        <property name="switchOn" value="LoadImage"/>

    </bean>
```

Now inform MessageDispatcherServlet to use the extended WebServiceMessageReceiverHandlerAdapter by adding an init-param in web.xml

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring-ws</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.ws.transport.http.MessageDispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>transformWsdlLocations</param-name>
      <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>messageReceiverHandlerAdapterBeanName</param-name>
        <param-value>switchableMessageReciever</param-value>
    </init-param>
  </servlet>
```